# How to import the npgsql module?

Tags: postgresql, powershell, npgsql

I need to connect to a PostgreSQL database from within PowerShell scripts. But how to install npgsql WITHOUT VisualStudio? There is no nuget!

So I tried to install the driver in the GAC using the newest MSI file (`Npgsql-3.0.5.msi`).

Using `gacutil.exe` shows, that it is installed:

> Npgsql, Version=3.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7, processorArchitecture=MSIL

But PowerShell does not know anything about it! `Get-Module -ListAvailable` should show it but:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (gmo -l n*).Name

NetAdapter  
NetConnection  
NetEventPacketCapture  
NetLbfo  
NetNat  
NetQos  
NetSecurity  
NetSwitchTeam  
NetTCPIP  
NetWNV  
NetworkConnectivityStatus  
NetworkLoadBalancingClusters  
NetworkTransition  
NFS  
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> _
```

There is no module `Npgsql`!

I was searching for `Npgsql.dll` and it is there:

```
PS  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Npgsql\v4.0_3.0.5.0__5d8b90d52f46fda7> dir

Verzeichnis: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Npgsql\v4.0_3.0.5.0__5d8b90d52f46fda7


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        08.01.2016     08:10     446464 Npgsql.dll


PS C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Npgsql\v4.0_3.0.5.0__5d8b90d52f46fda7> _
```

Because of the not recognised module `npgsql` my PowerShell code does not work:

```
function getDBConnection ($MyDBServer, $MyDBPort, $MyDatabase, $MyUid, $MyPwd) {
  $DBConnectionString = "Provider=PostgreSQL OLE DB Provider;Data Source=$MyDBServer;location=$MyDatabase;User ID=$MyUid;password=$MyPwd;timeout=1000;"
  $DBConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection;
  $DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString
  try {
    $DBConn.Open
  } catch {
    "Failed to connect! Error: "+ $_.Exception.Message
  }

  return $DBConn
}

function closeDBConnection ($DBConn) {
  $DBConn.Close
}

$query = "select * from test_table1"
$MyDBConnection = getDBConnection "dbserver" 5432 "databasename" "user" "pass"

try {
  $cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($query, $MyDBConnection)
} catch {
  "Failed to create command object! Error: " + $_.Exception.Message
}
...
```

The `$DBConn.Open` doesn't fail, but the property `ConnectionState` remains `Closed` after the `Open` call.

The creation of an instance of `OleDbCommand` crashes with a german error message:

> Failed to create command object! Error: Für "OleDbCommand" und die folgende Argumenteanzahl kann keine Überladung gefunden werden: "2".

It means that there are no overloaded methods with two parameters.

**QUESTIONS:**

- What do I need to install/configure so that `Npgsql` is visible in PowerShell?
- How do I load/import the `Npgsql` module in a PowerShell script or module?

Comment: I have no idea how to make things work in Powershell but it's definitely not true that Npgsql has no nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding. I do NOT have Visual Studio and I thought it works ONLY with VS! I saw that nuget has a commandline tools as well. - Your software works fine with Powershell since it can use everything from .NET. I managed to install it, see my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849700.aspx). `Get-Module -ListAvailable` only lists modules from the directories listed in [`$env:PSModulePath`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878326.aspx).

> **-ListAvailable**
>
> Gets all installed modules. **Get-Module** gets modules in paths listed in the **PSModulePath** environment variable. Without this parameter, **Get-Module** gets only the modules that are both listed in the **PSModulePath** environment variable, and that are loaded in the current session. **ListAvailable** does not return information about modules that are not found in the **PSModulePath** environment variable, even if those modules are loaded in the current session.

However, you can simply import any module with its full path in your script:

```
Import-Module 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Npgsql\v4.0_3.0.5.0__5d8b90d52f46fda7\Npgsql.dll'
```

Using wildcards in the path is allowed:

```
Import-Module 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Npgsql\*\Npgsql.dll'
```

If you want to be able to load the module by name create a subfolder `Npgsql` in one of the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath` and put the DLL into that subfolder.

Comment: Hmm, does not work. Don't know, if this DLL is usable in Powershell. I loaded it with the full path, wildcards and also copied it to a directory which is in $env:PSModulePath. Get-Command npgsql returns ObjectNotFound.

Comment: Afaik, Npgsql does not contain any Powershell module, it is simply a library that can be used in a regular .net project to connect to a PostgreSql database. It it however possible to use regular .Net libraries in Powershell, see @ThommyB's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, solved it! Here the solution:

Using Windows 8.1 with several .NET versions up to version 4.5 we can use Npgsql 3.0.5.

1. Download Npgsql-3.0.5.msi from the npgsql website and run the installer
2. Search for a DLL named 'Npgsql.ll'
3. Copy this dll to your local project directory (where you have your powershell script)
4. In the script Load the DLL using Add-Type -Path ".\Npgsql.dll"
5. Now you are ready to go!

Here some sample code where I connected to a PostgreSQL server running on a remote CentOS server:

```
Add-Type -Path ".\Npgsql.dll"

function getDBConnection ($MyDBServer, $MyDBPort, $MyDatabase, $MyUid, $MyPwd) {
$DBConnectionString = "server=$MyDBServer;port=$MyDBPort;user id=$MyUid;password=$MyPwd;database=$MyDatabase;pooling=false"
$DBConn = New-Object Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection;
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString
$DBConn.Open()

return $DBConn
}

function closeDBConnection ($DBConn)
{
    $DBConn.Close
}

$MyDBConnection = getDBConnection "db.mydomain.com" 5432 "databasename" "username" "password"
$query = "SELECT * FROM test_table1;"
$DBCmd = $MyDBConnection.CreateCommand()
$DBCmd.CommandText = $query
$adapter = New-Object -TypeName Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter $DBCmd
$dataset = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset)
$dataset.Tables[0]
closeDBConnection($MyDBConnection)
.....
```

npgsql seems to be compatible with System.Data.OleDb. So the OleDb documentation on technet.microsoft.com can be used as a reference.

Comment: Works like a charm, does anyone have any Idea why it does not work with subsequent versions of Npgsql? When I attempted the exact same strategy on the latest package (currently 3.2.0), I got a lot of dependendy problems where Powershell complained that it couldnt find a whole range of .net dll's

Comment: There's no more msi available, so I used the following:
install-package npgsql -source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -ProviderName NuGet -SkipDependencies -Force
This got me version 8.0.1, the latest.  Then @ThommyB's intructions work.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably a bit late but here is how Npgsql Version 4.0.2 can be included in powershell on Windows 10

1. Register the packagesource NuGet with:
   register-PackageSource -provider NuGet -name nugetRepository -location http://www.nuget.org/api/v2
2. In a powershell console with Administrator rights enter the command:
   Find-Package Npgsql | Install-Package
   positively answer the security questions

3. Enter:


   Get-Package Npgsql 


   and you will see the newly installed package Npgsql
/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to install MSI and had a hard time to add Npgsql.dll from nuget package.  It has dependencies from other assemblies, I was trying to collect them separately, but got different kind of errors while adding them.

The solution was to build assemblies using their repo on git hub. It worked on Win10 and then I was able to use same assemblies on win 2012.

Clone or download/unzip the repo:
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql

Open Npgsql.sln with Visual Studio, then build/build solution (might see some errors, ignore)

Then copy dlls from repofolder\npgsql\src\Npgsql\bin\Debug\net452 to your PS project

Then use snippet below to add all these assemblies:

```
$bin = "C:\folder\with\DLLs"

Add-Type -Path "$bin\Npgsql.dll" -ReferencedAssemblies "$bin\System.*.dll"

$str =  "Server=yourserver;Port=1521;Username=user;Password=pass;Database=somedb"

$conn = New-Object Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection $str 

$conn.Open()
```