# Escape quotes in psql command when running from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, psql

```
& "psql" "-d" "yourdb" "-h" "localhost" "-p" "5432" "-U" "youruser" "-c" "select foo from bar where data @> `'{ `"key`" : `"value`" }`';"
```

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
>   LINE 1: ...foo from bar where data @> '{ key...

How do I escape that command string so that `psql` will not throw up?

Comment: Don't use the commandline client. Use the [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/) or [ODBC](https://odbc.postgresql.org/) driver.

Comment: Since I am trying to script this in powershell, that kinda defeats the purpose

Comment: How so? You'd still write a PowerShell script, but using a driver gives you far better control than the commandline client provides.

Comment: Because I am trying to write a debugging snippet fast and psql support the -c switch so if its possible to execute something like the above I would prefer it instead of digging into a bigger solution

Comment: If you use the Npgsql dll [like this post describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674761/how-to-import-the-npgsql-module) you can get away from string/pipe/escape and format problems with both input and output. The query result will resemble the output of any other PowerShell command (which means you can use format-table, export-csv, etc). With the command line client you will have far fewer options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use the [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/) or [psqlODBC](https://odbc.postgresql.org/) driver, since they have numerous advantages when it comes to the handling of basically everything (connections, arguments, results, errors, …).

However, if you insist on using the commandline client you can fix the syntax error by adding backslashes to escape the nested double quotes for the execution of the external command (the backticks are just to escape them for the PowerShell parser):

```bsh
"SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE data @> '{ \`"key\`" : \`"value\`" }';"
#                                     ^     ^     ^       ^
```

The single quotes don't need escaping.

I would also recommend using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Splatting?view=powershell-3.0) for passing the arguments:

```bsh
$params = '-d', 'yourdb',
          '-h', 'localhost',
          '-p', 5432,
          '-U', 'youruser',
          '-c', "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE data @> '{\`"key\`":\`"value\`"}';"

& 'psql.exe' @params
```

Note that you must invoke `psql.exe` with its (absolute or relative) path if the directory containing the executable is not in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for the "backslash" tip. HOURS saved.